# post one score for each game level

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, game-center

there are in some place of documentation any information about multiple scores (one for each game level)?

I know how to do a leaderboard using score API, and how to publish a achievement, but I'd like know how to do a leaderboard for each level like angry birds friends.

There is some way?

Thanks.